Background Location Permission enabled for my app. Playstore rejected my app, what is the fix?
I am building a live tracking feature for the order delivery where we can track current position for my order. The app is made in Flutter. In the driver side I have enabled Background Location Permission also in the manifest.xml. But this turns into a play store rejection.
I am attaching the rejection message below:

After a recent review, we found that your app AppName is not compliant with one or more of our Developer Program Policies. See below for more information about your app's status and how to correct the issue.
Publishing Status
App Status: Rejected
Your app has been rejected and wasn't published due to the policy issue(s) listed below. If you submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still available on Google Play.
Issue found: Feature doesn’t not meet requirements to access location in the background
Based on our review, your declared feature doesn’t appear to meet our Location Permissions policy requirements. When declaring a feature for background location access, it’s important to:
Only choose a feature if it delivers clear value to your users and is important to your app’s core functionality or main purpose. Without this core feature, your app is “broken” or rendered unusable.
Consider whether users would expect your app to access their location in the background and whether you can deliver the same experience without accessing location in the background.

I am attaching my Manifest.xml permission part
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>

I am attaching how I am implementing my location logic while the app is backgrounded.
Future<void> _listenLocation() async {
model.location.enableBackgroundMode(enable: true);
locationStream = model.location.onLocationChanged.listen((event) async {
  logger.w("Is it Working.....");
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('location')
      .doc(widget.orderId.toString())
      .set({
    'latitude': event.latitude,
    'longitude': event.longitude,
    'dishOrderId': widget.orderId.toString()
  }, SetOptions(merge: true));
});
}

In the play console, in app content where the purpose for location permission can be defined  I have added the below statements.

App Purpose: BitesVilla app is used to order, track and delivery of food. Driver, Seller and User are summarized in a single app only. Main purpose of the app is to live track the order during delivery. The live tracking of order/driver can be done by Customer.
Location Access: The app uses background location to live track the delivery of order. Background location permission is required so that accurate live tracking of the order/driver can be done by Customer even when the app is closed or not in used (backgrounded).

I know there must be certain ways to do that. But as I don't have much expertise with the permission related stuff so am getting stuck and rejected again and again.

I don't know much about particular "background location" permission, but generally, I think for these kind of sensetive permissions, runtime permission asking is must. So, I think you can do that.

@VanshPatel as per my implementation I need the permission to update drivers lat long to the server when his app is minimized. That's the catch brother

I know that you require permission for background. But, I think you should ask for that permission in runtime when you app is first installed and first opened, then I think you can save the position.

@VanshPatel sir google documentation is saying ask for the permission only when it is required . So I am accessing the permission request when the driver is ready for picking up

So, in short you are asking for permission to driver before accessing in background, right?

Yeah @VanshPatel

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

You will have to, provide the necessary reason along with a demo video of your app using the background location and why is it required, all this to Play Console, they will check and then might approve your app. You have to explain your intentions clearly.

@MeetMiyani I have done that already

I see, @ArnabGhosh what does the play console support team says? Did you tried contacting them?
